# ¿Como iterar una colección Request.Form?

Tags: c#, mvc, razor

tengo un formulario con 9 campos, al pulsar el botón submit mando esos datos al `Action CrearUsuario()`.
Mi idea es iterar cada campo para comprobar si hay alguno vacío. Para esto estoy intentando usar un `foreach` en el `Request.Form` pero no da resultado.
Aca paso el código:

```html
 public ActionResult CrearUsuario()
        {
           
            ViewBag.Msg = "";
            //checkeando inputs vacios
            foreach(String item in Request.Form)
            {
                if(item == null)
                {
                    ViewBag.Msg = "Hay campos vacios!";
                    return View();
                }
            }
            
            ViewBag.Msg = "usuario creado!";
            return view();
```

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿Que lenguaje es?

Comment: Hola @ jonasdamher! gracias por responder..es C#, Razor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberias capturar los datos con un FormCollection y ahi iterar la data. De todas formas existen muchas maneras de validar que los campos no lleguen vacio desde el cliente.

Aqui te dejo como iterar el FormCollection y devolver si viene un campo nulo.

Saludos

Controlador

```
  public ActionResult Guardar(FormCollection _data)
        {
            ViewBag.msg = string.Empty;
            foreach (var item in _data)
            {
                string valor = _data[item.ToString()];
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(valor))
                {
                    ViewBag.Msg = "El campo " + item.ToString() + " esta vacio";
                    return View();
                }
            }
            ViewBag.Msg = "Campos Validos";
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Gracias @mrCL!!!